# Insert dll code inside executable to make it free from dependecies

Tags: c++, dll

I've an executable with a lot of dll from which it import function. I need to know if there's a way to insert the code of .dll inside the .exe to make it free from others file,so to have just the executable distributed.
Thanks to who'll answer.

Answer (score 1):

The point of a DLL (Dynamic Link Library) is that it **is** separate from the executable. There's no conventional way to do so since the DLL is precompiled, meaning that a compiler cannot reference the source code and directly compile it to your executable.

If you have the source of the library, you can compile the library statically with your executable and then they will all be output into a single executable file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible, but you need 3rd party tools. You need so-called "exe bundle", just google it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check why did you created a dll in the first place .   http://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/c/difference-between-static-and-dynamic-linking.php . Changing from dll to static linking lib might defeat some basic design purpose .

Answer (score -2):

Quinn Kirwan has provided the right answer, you need the source code of all the dll's that you have linked to your exe. Then you have to go to the project properties and liker properties and select the option to statically link the dll's. On successful steps you will get a single exe. Please note that the size of this exe will be much larger than the one you have now. Because all the functionality provided by the dll's will be part of the exe now.

Thanks